# Matlab coder Non-constant expression or empty matrix

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am trying to make a function made by Matlab transformed into MEX file to enhance execution speed of the function but the coder show the error:

> Non-constant expression or empty matrix. This expression must be
>   constant because its value determines the size or class of some
>   expression.

The part of the code that causes the problem is

```
indx=mat==max(mat);
nominees={acceptedB{indx,:}};
```

I also tried not to use logical indexing using

```
indx=find(mat==max(mat));
```

but the same error appeared.
any idea how to solve this problem without affecting execution speed of the function ?

Comment: What are the sizes of `mat` and `acceptedB`?

Comment: Expected size of mat is 100x1 doubles and expected size for acceptedB is 100x2 cell arrays

Comment: What does `max(mat)` output?

Comment: A double like 5.134

Comment: Are you sure? If `mat` is indeed a vector, the only case where this wouldn't work would be if every value in `mat` is NaN

Comment: No I checked all the values in mat must be double values between 1 and 6